# twitteR - searchTwitter returns truncated Text field

Tags: r, twitter

The searchTwitter method of twitteR package return truncated 'text' field for tweets. For e.g "Twitter is a goo... "

How can I get full text of Tweets using twitteR package?

Following is my code for getting tweet.

```
tweets<-searchTwitter("Honda" , n=5, lang="en", since=NULL, until=NULL, locale=NULL, geocode=NULL, sinceID=NULL, maxID=NULL, resultType=NULL, retryOnRateLimit=120)
# put tweets in a data frame
tweets<-twListToDF(tweets)

# write out to a CSV file
write.csv(tweets, file="filename.csv")
```

Comment: May you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Use `rtweet` package instead. `twitteR` is outdated and not further developed afaik.

Comment: @JonnyCrunch I have added the code I am using above in my question. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that's not just an artifact of a print method? Sometimes print methods just give the first portion of an object but there more there than shows.

Comment: It is the file that I am looking into for 'text' of tweets. I have updated my code above to show how I am writing my file. Thanks